# OnError script task not constructing error messages

Tags: vb.net, ssis, event-handling

I have a script task(onError event handler) which gets the system error messages and stores them in the errorMessages user variable. The below script never finishes and goes in loop. I am trying to implement [this link for sending email failure notifications](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/05/05/handling-multiple-errors-in-ssis/). Any thoughts where this is going wrong?

```
        Dim messages As Collections.ArrayList
    Try
        messages = CType(Dts.Variables("errorMessages").Value, Collections.ArrayList)
    Catch ex As Exception
        messages = New Collections.ArrayList()
    End Try
    messages.Add(Dts.Variables("ErrorDescription").Value.ToString())
    ' MessageBox.Show("Arraylist constructed")
    Dts.Variables("errorMessages").Value = messages
    'Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Comment: You are not storing the result from `ex`.

Comment: Found the issue. The errorMessages variable was originally a string type which was wrong. It was supposed to be type object. Problem solved.

Comment: And thank you for the encouraging downvote on the question (to whoever did it). Sometimes, it makes me wonder if this site really likes to help people or just wants to moderate everything in their sight. Anyways, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check the declaration type of the errorMessages variable. I mistakenly declared it as string but it had to be type object. Changing that resolved the issue. Just posting it here in case someone faces similar issue.